# How to make item of stackview auto resized for resizable widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, stackview

I tested stackwidget from android developer sample and I modified the widget to be resizable. But what happened is, when I resize the widget, the item is not resized but only add more space between items. How do I make item size to adapt resizable widget size? I see on youtube widget, the item was able to do so. Could anyone please show me how to do that? Thank you.